# How can I fail a GatsbyJS production build that uses MDX if a component prop is invalid?

Tags: gatsby

GatsbyJS enables the creation of pages uses [MDX](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/) - an extended version of Markdown that allows you to use React components inline.

I can then allow non-technical people to create content for a Gatsby website and they can embed components where needed within a page.

So imagine I've created a component called `MagicalVideo` and it needs a prop passing in called `name`, used like so:

```
# Markdown title yay

<MagicalVideo name="some_name" />
```

Imagine that the `name` prop isn't just required, but it has to follow a particular pattern - say, snake case.

The question I'm looking to answer is: how do I validate the `name` prop during the GatsbyJS production build?

To clarify, if I do something like so:

```
const MagicalVideo = ({ name }) => {
    if (isInvalid(name)) {
        throw new Error('name bad, baaaaaaad')
    }
```

This will fail in the browser *not* at build time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code

```
const MagicalVideo = ({ name }) => {
    throw new Error('component goes boom')
};
```

In `gatsby develop` it will fail only on the client.

Turns out that at `gatsby build` time it will fail the build, as I wanted.

Leaving here for anyone else who asks my (stupid) question :)

Answer (score 0):

From 
   `const MagicalVideo = ({ name }) => {
    if (isInvalid(name)) {
        throw new Error('name bad, baaaaaaad')
    }`

To

```
const MagicalVideo = ({ name }) => {
  const specials = /[^A-Za-z]/g;
  console.log(specials.test(name));
  if (specials.test(name) === true) {
    throw new Error("name bad, baaaaaaad");
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the question is actually about failing the production build of Gatsby JS, not the validation itself.